Ubuntu Desktop Running on HP ProDesk Shutting Down When Left Alone
I'm trying to use this old desktop from work as a machine to at least run pihole on, maybe a few other things as well. But pihole is job number 1. Got that going, set all my power settings so that it never goes to sleep, went to bed.
Next morning, no internet access on my network. The desktop LOOKS like it's working (the LEDS in the ethernet cable port are flashing, LEDS in the wired gaming mouse light up...) but the monitor doesn't detect a video signal and when I check my router's attached devices list, the Ubuntu desktop isn't on it. Have to do a hard reboot.
Boots up fine, I fiddle with another power setting (set monitor to never sleep, then just unplugged the monitor cable), and go to work. Wife calls me a couple hours later to say the internet isn't working.
I'm looking at my logs and at my BIOS settings to see if there's something to do with power or and error leading to a freeze, but nothing is jumping out at me. Here's the logs from this morning from around the time I started it up and left for work.
08:31:29 kernel: workqueue: output_poll_execute [drm_kms_helper] hogged CPU for >10000us 16 times, consider switching to WQ_UNBOUND
08:31:29 kernel: workqueue: output_poll_execute [drm_kms_helper] hogged CPU for >10000us 16 times, consider switching to WQ_UNBOUND
08:23:26 kernel: workqueue: output_poll_execute [drm_kms_helper] hogged CPU for >10000us 8 times, consider switching to WQ_UNBOUND
08:19:26 kernel: workqueue: output_poll_execute [drm_kms_helper] hogged CPU for >10000us 4 times, consider switching to WQ_UNBOUND
08:16:42 kernel: loop13: detected capacity change from 0 to 26472
08:16:40 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1719785800.751:125): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="ubuntu_pro_esm_cache//apt_methods_gpgv" name="/var/lib/dpkg/arch" pid=3515 comm="dpkg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=105 ouid=0
08:16:39 kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 12 callbacks suppressed
08:16:31 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1719785791.751:103): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="ubuntu_pro_esm_cache//apt_methods_gpgv" name="/var/lib/dpkg/arch" pid=2805 comm="dpkg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=105 ouid=0
08:16:31 kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 23 callbacks suppressed
08:16:29 kernel: Initializing XFRM netlink socket
08:16:29 kernel: Bridge firewalling registered
08:16:29 kernel: bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
08:16:26 kernel: audit: type=1326 audit(1719785786.591:70): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4 subj=snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration pid=1777 comm="snapd-desktop-i" exe="/snap/snapd-desktop-integration/157/usr/bin/snapd-desktop-integration" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=203 compat=0 ip=0x7687909ed531 code=0x50000
08:16:26 kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 50 callbacks suppressed
08:16:26 kernel: rfkill: input handler disabled
08:16:25 kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
08:16:25 kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno1: NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
08:16:22 kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input10
08:16:22 kernel: snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x1a
08:16:22 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
08:16:22 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
08:16:22 kernel: input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input4
08:16:22 kernel: ACPI: video: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
08:16:22 kernel: [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20201103 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
08:16:22 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:121:DDI D/PHY D] is disabled/in DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
08:16:22 kernel: loop13: detected capacity change from 0 to 8
08:16:22 kernel: intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain psys
08:16:22 kernel: intel_tcc_cooling: Programmable TCC Offset detected
08:16:22 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0100 -> 0102)
08:16:22 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
08:16:22 kernel: mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_ops [i915])
08:16:22 kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
08:16:21 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1719785781.815:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=482 comm="apparmor_parser"
08:16:21 kernel: AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
08:16:21 kernel: AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
08:16:21 kernel: input: HP WMI hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input3
08:16:21 kernel: cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
08:16:21 kernel: hp_wmi: query 0x4 returned error 0x5
08:16:21 kernel: 0x000000000000-0x000002000000 : "BIOS"
08:16:21 kernel: Creating 1 MTD partitions on "0000:00:1f.5":
08:16:21 kernel: RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain psys 2^-14 Joules
08:16:21 kernel: spi-nor spi0.0: w25q256 (32768 Kbytes)
08:16:21 kernel: mei_me 0000:00:16.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
08:16:21 kernel: ee1004 0-0050: 512 byte EE1004-compliant SPD EEPROM, read-only
08:16:21 kernel: EDAC ie31200: No ECC support
08:16:21 kernel: loop12: detected capacity change from 0 to 904
08:16:21 kernel: loop11: detected capacity change from 0 to 952
08:16:21 kernel: loop10: detected capacity change from 0 to 79520
08:16:21 kernel: loop9: detected capacity change from 0 to 82800
08:16:21 kernel: loop8: detected capacity change from 0 to 25240
08:16:21 kernel: loop7: detected capacity change from 0 to 187776
08:16:21 kernel: loop6: detected capacity change from 0 to 1034424
08:16:21 kernel: loop5: detected capacity change from 0 to 1017816
08:16:21 kernel: loop4: detected capacity change from 0 to 550200

The "workqueue" error shows up as the last log entry on the night I set everything up, as well.
I was thinking the problem might be something with the HP BIOS, because I've had a similar issue with these same machines running Windows 10. But I wasn't able to find anything in the BIOS that looked like it needed to be changed.
System Information:
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Intel i7-8700T @2.4GHz
8GB RAM
HP 83EF motherboard
Any help would be much appreciated. Let me know if I need to provide more information.

Welcome to AskUbuntu. HP devices are notorious for requiring a monitor to be connected in order to stay on. If the monitor is disconnected or powered off, many older desktops will automatically shut down. This is because many office workers used to shut their monitors off at the end of the day but not the computer, so lots of electricity was wasted. In the HP BIOS, there may also be a power setting that looks something like “headless” or “run as server”. This will be required for the BIOSes internal idle check to be disabled. His have long been “tricky” about this sort of thing.

@matigo, thanks, that's helpful to know, and might explain why the other HP ProDesk I have running in a cabinet at work with no monitor seems to shut itself off.

My guess is that you've done something to disrupt the DNS on your network. It could also be a DHCP issue: you might be inadvertently running two DHCP servers. You should go through DNS and network debugging using a previously known working machine on the network. You might find the ping, dig and tcpdump/dhcpdump tools useful for this

Thanks, @moo, but the Pihole/network side was running great. It's the unresponsive machine / unexpected shutdown that's puzzling me. As soon as I switched the Prodesk back on, the Pihole was working fine.
I had been running a Pihole on my Synology for a couple weeks, but realised I was probably going to send my HDDs to an early death with all that read/write. That was the main reason for getting this old desktop (with an SSD) running.

@matigo, I couldn't find anything in the HP BIOS that I could edit. Even downloaded the config file and tried editing that. This machine might just be unsuitable for this purpose.
